# Passing serializable object to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, serialization

I use the putExtra and getSerializable Methods to pass my object to a second activity. It works fine, however, am I required to return this object in order to maintain the changes made in the second activity?

When I run my app, and launch my second activity then call `finish()` after makimg a change to the object passed to it, if I relaunch that second activity the old object data previous to the change is displayed, does this mean that using the put/get serializable methods are passing a clone of the object, and that in order to keep the changes made on the second activity I must repass the object back to the main activity ?!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why would you require such behaviour.However you can try the following methods.

You can make that object as global static variable(preferably in the application class of the app) so that the object is retained between different instances of the activities.

Also if the state of the object is important across app restarts you must plan to write the state of the object in some persistent storage like db/file/shared preference.Refer this [link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076120/java-se/flatten-your-objects.html) for storing object,

Comment: I want to avoid using static or putting a reference to it in the android manifest. Can you explain how I can go about saving the state in persistent storage?